# How to add django-reversion to an app developed using django and django-rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-reversion

I have an app developed using Django and Django Rest framework. I would like to add the django-reversion feature to my app.

I have already tried http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#low-level-api but I have failed to make specific changes to my app.

Below are the modules of the app where I would like to include the Django-reversion to restore objects if they get deleted. How to set the django-reversion configuration for the below modules

**admin.py:-**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from.models import Category

admin.site.register(Category)
```

**models.py:-**

```
  from django.db import models
  class Category(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

**serializers.py:-**

```
        from rest_framework import serializers
        from .models import Category

        class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
              courses = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
                  many=True
                  read_only=True
                  view_name='course-detail'
               )
               class Meta:
                     model = Category
                     fields = ('pk', 'name', 'courses',)
```

**urls.py :-**

```
            from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
            from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
            from .import views
            from django.conf.urls import include

            category_list = views.CategoryViewSet.as_view({
                'get': 'list',
                'post': 'create'
            })

            category_detail = views.CategoryViewSet.as_view({
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'put': 'update',
                'patch': 'partial_update',
                'delete': 'destroy',
           })

           urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([

                url(r'^categories/$',
                    category_list,
                    name='category-list'),
                url(r'^categories/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
                    category_detail,
                    name='category-detail'),
           ])

           urlpatterns += [
               url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                                          namespace='rest_framework')),
           ]
```

**views.py :-**

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Category
from .serializers import CategorySerializer

class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = Category.objects.all()
 serializer_class = CategorySerializer
 permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedorReadOnly,)
```

Comment: Nice!! Thanks for saving a lot of time!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [The simplest way to create revisions is to use reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#revisionmiddleware). This will automatically wrap every request in a revision, ensuring that all changes to your models will be added to their version history.
>
> To enable the revision middleware, simply add it to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting as follows:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware',
    # Other middleware goes here...
)
```

Any thing more complex with this will require adding API calls through your code in away that wraps specific `save` calls in ways that *you* decide.

Comment: Ya I did add the middleware classes and I'm more into admin and low-level API integration of my above modules using django-reversion documentation. by the way, I was able to proceed the admin integration yesterday but my question what is the difference between admin integration and low-level API integration ?

Comment: Atleast I'm able to see the django-reversion feature in backend admin:

Answer (score 1):

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from.models import Category
import reversion

class BaseReversionAdmin(reversion.VersionAdmin):
 pass

admin.site.register(Category, BaseReversionAdmin)
```

also added reversion to installed_apps and middlewareclasses.

Finally i could see the "recover deleted objects button".

Comment: I would like to know "How to query" and "How to populate history page"

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that since `rest_framework.viewsets.ModelViewSet` inherits from `django.views.generic.View` so you can also use the `reversion.views.RevisionMixin` to create revisions instead of having to use the middleware if you want.

From the question above this would look like the following:

```py
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Category
from .serializers import CategorySerializer
from reversion.views import RevisionMixin

class CategoryViewSet(RevisionMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedorReadOnly,)
```

You can read more about the specifics of how you can use `RevisionMixin` here: https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/views.html#reversion-views-revisionmixin