# How to provide view for django-reversion History objects?

Tags: django, django-reversion

Admin integration for django reversion is pretty straightforward.
When I visit `127.0.0.1/admin` I have the option for staff users to recover deleted objects or view previous versions.

But this is only from the admin side. How can I provide a public view for history objects? I'm attempting to provide history access via Django-REST-Framework.

Comment: what are you using for REST API? tastypie? DRF? other?

Comment: I'm using it for REST API. previously I have implemented  django-reversion for admin integration @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593989/how-to-add-django-reversion-to-an-app-developed-using-django-and-django-rest-fra for your cross reference

Answer (score 4):

## Tastypie Approach

- Create a resource for `Version (from reversion.models import Version)` with resource_name as `'versions'`
- Add the following url pattern to `prepend_urls` to the resources for which you have enabled reversion:

  ```
  url(r'^(?P<resource_name>{})/(?P<pk>\d+)/history{1}$'.format(self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('dispatch_history'), name='history')
  ```
- Paste the following code into the resource:

  ```
  def dispatch_history(self, request, **kwargs):
      try:
          bundle = self.build_bundle(data={
              'pk': kwargs['pk']
          }, request=request)
          obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
      except ObjectDoesNotExist:
          return HttpGone()

      _versions = reversion.get_for_object(obj)
      versions = []
      for version in _versions:
          _resource = api.canonical_resource_for('versions')
          _bundle = _resource.build_bundle(version)
          _bundle = _resource.full_dehydrate(_bundle)
          versions.append(_bundle)
      return self.create_response(request, versions)
  ```

Disclaimer: This code hasn't been tested, if it works in one go, then praise the lord.

<strike>PS: I'll be implementing a similar thing with DRF soon. Will update the answer when done.</strike>

## Django Rest Framework

```
class VersionableModelViewSetMixin(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @detail_route()
    def history(self, request, pk=None):
        _object = self.get_object()
        _versions = reversion.get_for_object(_object)

        _context = {
            'request': request
        }

        _version_serializer = VersionSerializer(_versions, many=True, context=_context)
        # TODO
        # check pagination
        return Response(_version_serializer.data)
```

Include this Mixin in all the views containing models that have been registered with django-reversion.

Hope this helps a bit.

Best!!