# How to get previous object value after changing its name using django reversion?

Tags: python, django, django-reversion

In [How to add django-reversion to an app developed using django and django-rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593989/how-to-add-django-reversion-to-an-app-developed-using-django-and-django-rest-fra) I have added the below function to get history of objects

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from reversion.models import Version
import json

def history_list(request):
   history_list = Version.objects.all().order_by('-revision__date_created')

data = []
for i in history_list:
    data.append({
        'date_time': str(i.revision.date_created),
        'user': str(i.revision.user),
        'object': i.object_repr,
        'type': i.content_type.name,
        'comment': i.revision.comment
    })

data_ser = json.dumps(data)
return HttpResponse(data_ser, content_type="application/json")
```

In the urls.py of [How to add django-reversion to an app developed using django and django-rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593989/how-to-add-django-reversion-to-an-app-developed-using-django-and-django-rest-fra) I have added a route to history.

When I visit 127.0.0.1:8000/history I get the json data as

```
[{"object": "someobject", "user": "someuseruser", "type": "sometype", "comment": "Changed name.", "date_time": "2015-03-02 18:04:58.368650+00:00"}]
```

**execution flow**: When I visit 127.0.0.1:8000/admin and change the value of above object to "otherobject". when I refresh 127.0.0.1:8000/history. I get one more json field

```
[{"object": "otherobject", "user": "someuseruser", "type": "sometype", "comment": "Changed name.", "date_time": "2015-03-02 18:04:58.368650+00:00"}]
```

below is the area I got stuck to add one more additional field to history function:

I would like to  include one more field to above iteration in history function. like previous_object: " " to get the object name before its changed even after changing name.
for instance:-
from 127.0.0.1:8000/admin
I changed object name from "apple" to "orange".

When I visit the history route 127.0.0.1:8000/history

```
[{"object": "apple", "object_before_changed": ""null": "someuseruser", "type": "sometype", "comment": "Changed name.", "date_time": "2015-03-02 18:00:58.368650+00:00"}]
```

I should be able to see as below

```
[{"object": "orange", "object before_changed": ""apple": "someuseruser", "type": "sometype", "comment": "Changed name.", "date_time": "2015-03-02 18:04:58.368650+00:00"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to setup a variable to hold to previous item and insert it into the dictionary as required. note that this uses [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) as a way to get the `object_repr` of `previous_object` and safely provide a default if there is none (as would be the case for the first iteration).

```
data = []
previous_object = None
for i in history_list:
    data.append({
        'date_time': str(i.revision.date_created),
        'user': str(i.revision.user),
        'object': i.object_repr,
        'previous_object': getattr(previous_object,'object_repr',None),
        'type': i.content_type.name,
        'comment': i.revision.comment
    })
    previous_object = i
```

Comment: OUTPUT:-
[{"previous_object": null, "comment": "Changed name.", "type": "sometype", "user": "someuser", "object": "newobject", "date_time": "2015-03-03 01:16:00.529507+00:00"}, {"previous_object": "newobject", "comment": "Changed name.", "type": "sometype", "user": "someuser", "object": "someobject", "date_time": "2015-03-03 01:15:20.657896+00:00"}]

I would like to get output as example below:
for instance:
original object:"apple"
after i went into admin and changed original object:"orange"
it should represent previous object: apple, original object:orange

Comment: Edit that into your question so you can format it properly, its hard to understand.